Unable to Verify the provider
I'm setting up a Pact POC for our project and coming across the below error while trying to verify the Provider against the pact file in Pactbroker
Failed to load pact - No pacts found for provider 'xxxx' matching the given consumer version selectors in pact broker '``https://myorg.pactflow.io``': IO Error - Request to pact broker path '' failed: 401 Unauthorized. URL: '``https://myorg.pactflow.io``'
Below is my Provider spec
const opts = { 
logLevel: "INFO", 
providerBaseUrl: "URL of the Provider", 
provider: "xxxx",
 providerVersion: "1.0.0", 
providerVersionBranch: "test", 
consumerVersionSelectors: [ { mainBranch: true } ], 
pactBrokerUrl: process.env.PACT_BROKER_URL || "https://myorg-d74b.pactflow.io", pactBrokerUsername: process.env.PACT_BROKER_USERNAME || "user", 
pactBrokerPassword: process.env.PACT_BROKER_PASSWORD || "pswd", 
requestFilter: (req, res, next) => { 
if (!req.headers["authorization"]) { 
next(); 
return; 
} req.headers["authorization"] = Bearer xxxx; next(); },


You're using pactBrokerPassword when you should be using the pactBrokerToken option.
See https://docs.pactflow.io/#configuring-your-api-token for more.

Yes, I did added it to the publish command

Yes, for publishing to the PACT I'm using a token . But the issue is happening during verification where it doesn't send the trigger to the Provider Base URL.
Below the script for publishing to broker
"test:publish": "./node_modules/.bin/pact-broker publish ./pacts --consumer-app-version=\"1.0.0\"  --auto-detect-version-properties --broker-base-url=https://org.pactflow.io --broker-token=xxxxxx"

The provider base URL should be your API, not the PactFlow URL
